# Facebook Mention Tag Design and Flow (friend picker then textarea with tag)

Tags: facebook-opengraph, tagging

I have a sending gifts app where a user can send a gift to a Facebook friend. I want to use the Mention Tagging Open Graph functionality to post on Facebook like the following:

Bob gave(action) a gift(object):
   Hey @John, have this coffee on me! Vero (message with friend John tagged)

Ideally, the user would select the recipient of the gift first (does not have to be a Facebook Friend), and then in the delivery details write the message and choose how to send the gift (Facebook, email, or text).

Can the user be tagged in the textarea already (since they have already selected a Facebook friend)? In the delivery details page we explicitly tell them that if they choose to post the gift on Facebook the friend will be tagged (we also clearly explain how to remove/add a different tagged person).

Kind of like the example of Facebook Camera having a friend picker icon and modal, but instead showing the friend picker modal **before** showing the textarea.

If unclear, I can send a mockup of the app and the website with more details on the flow.